# Order of evaluation of a simple term

Tags: arithmetic

If, for example, $a=14$, $b=2$ and $c=7$ and I'm working to (say) three decimal places, should I evaluate the term$$a\frac{b}{c},$$

in the order $$a\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)$$

or$$\frac{\left(ab\right)}{c}.$$

Or should I just say that the original term is inherently ambiguous?

Comment: If I had to choose, I would use the first interpretation on principle, but in the end it doesn't matter, so I can choose the third order out of convenience:
$$
\left(\frac ac\right)b
$$

Comment: Well, the two methods give slightly different answers (to three decimal places).

Comment: I didn't note the "to three decimal places". In that case, the third way (or the second) is _definitelty_ the better way, since the correct answer is $4$.